# AJAX JavaScript returning SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to write a JavaScript Function which finds the correct JSON object for a Country Name from a GeoJSON file. From this, it then extracts the Country Code. I want to then use the Country Code as a parameter to pass to an API in order to retrieve information about that country. This information is then shown in a modal

However, I seem to be getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php` - I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

**JavaScript**

```
let code

$('#innerSelect').on('change', async () => {     //Handles changing the country select.
  await addCountryBorder($('#innerSelect').val())  /* Calls function that adds country border to map */
  countryInfo($('#innerSelect').val())

  const result = await $.ajax({
    url: 'libs/php/getCoordsFromCountryName.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { countryName: $('#innerSelect').val() }
  })

  if (result.status.name == 'ok') {
    const { lat, lng } = result.data[0].geometry
    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng))
  }
});

/* Function responsible for adding border to a given country and grabbing country code*/
async function addCountryBorder (countryName) {
  const result = await $.ajax({
    url: 'assets/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {}
  })

  const features = result.features

  const countryFeature = findFeatureFromName(countryName)

  if (!countryFeature) return

  if (border) map.removeLayer(border)

  border = new L.geoJSON(countryFeature.geometry, {
    style: { color: '#006600' }
  }).addTo(map)

  map.panTo(border.getBounds().getCenter())
  map.fitBounds(border.getBounds())

  console.log(countryFeature)
}


function countryInfo(countryName) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "assets/geojson/countryBorders.geo.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            
        },
        success: function(result) {
            let features = result["features"];

            let countryFeature = findFeatureFromName(countryName);
            countryCode = JSON.stringify(countryFeature.properties.iso_a2)

            
            console.log(countryCode)
            
        $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/countryInfo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: countryCode,
        },
        success: function(result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#continent').html(result['data'][0]['continentName']);
                $('#capital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                $('#countryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                $('#population').html(formattedPopulation);
                $('#currencyCode').html(result['data'][0]['currencyCode']);


                }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
  });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=username&style=full';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Information</h4>
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h6 id="countryName" class="modal-sub-header"></h6>
          <hr>
          <ul class="dem">
            <li class="listItem">Capital City: <span class="test" id="capital"></span></li>
            <li class="listItem">Continent: <span class="test" id="continent"></span></li>
            <li class="listItem">Population: <span class="test" id="population"></span></li>
            <li class="listItem">Currency: <span class="test" id="currencyCode"></span></li>
            <li class="listItem">Area (km<sup>2</sup>): <span class="test" id="area"></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The error in the console looks like so

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php

    //"... is not valid JSON
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.5.1.js:9260:19)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9736:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047:9)
```

I believe the error to be to do with the `countryInfo.php` ajax call

Comment: You're getting `<?php` in your response, which means that it's not being run through the PHP interpreter/web server. Make sure that your URL in the address bar does not start with `file:///`

Comment: Oh sorry! The error is pointing at ```console.log(errorThrown);``` in the ```countryInfo``` function

Comment: @aynber I dont quite understand? Sorry

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?php` means that the response you're getting from the API starts with `<?php`. That usually means that the PHP file is returning raw PHP. This is usually due to a misconfigured webserver (if the URL starts with `http`), or you're running the page locally without a webserver (if the URL starts with `file:///`). All PHP files *must* be run through a webserver in order to be processed properly.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it seems to be ```countryInfo.php``` causing the issue as the ```console.log(code)``` for ```countryBorders.geo.json``` prints the expected output

Comment: @aynber the URL is set up in the ```countryInfo.php``` as ```$url='http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=username&style=full';```

Comment: That's the URL in the PHP, but the PHP isn't working. Ignore that part at the moment. The error you're getting is from javascript saying it doesn't like what PHP is sending back, because the PHP is not processing at all. What does the URL in the browser show?

Comment: @aynber The URL should return this JSON as thats how it opens in the browser  ```{"geonames": [{
  "continent": "EU",
  "capital": "Berlin",
  "languages": "de",
  "geonameId": 2921044,
  "south": 47.2701236047002,
  "isoAlpha3": "DEU",
  "north": 55.0583836008072,
  "fipsCode": "GM",
  "population": "82927922",
  "east": 15.0418156516163,
  "isoNumeric": "276",
  "areaInSqKm": "357021.0",
  "countryCode": "DE",
  "west": 5.8663152683722,
  "countryName": "Germany",
  "postalCodeFormat": "#####",
  "continentName": "Europe",
  "currencyCode": "EUR"
}]}```

Comment: @aynber http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&country=DE&username=demo&style=full  link to the browser for your understanding

Comment: **Ignore the PHP, ignore the API.** What does **your** browser show as the URL? The issue is the PHP is not being processed, `libs/php/getCoordsFromCountryName.php` is returning your code as text instead of actually running it. So you need to figure out why. Please read the linked duplicate, it gives explanations and fixes.